# How to open a single image in my app from file explorer

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, intentfilter

I am working on an app in which I want to open any photo in my app from external file explorer. Like when I click on photo, choose applications window appears and I select my app and image is shown in my app. But here, no image appears.

**I added code in `Manifest.xml`:**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.image.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

**Layout file `activity_main.xml`**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".DataReceiverActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="Receive Picture Sharing" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**And in my `MainActivity.java`:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
        TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
        String receivedAction = receivedIntent.getAction();
        String receivedType = receivedIntent.getType();

        // make sure it's an action and type we can handle
        if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
            if (receivedType.startsWith("text/")) {
                picView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String receivedText = receivedIntent
                    .getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                if (receivedText != null) {
                    txtView.setText(receivedText);
                }
            } else if (receivedType.startsWith("image/")) {
                txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Uri receivedUri = (Uri) receivedIntent
                    .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                if (receivedUri != null) {
                    picView.setImageURI(receivedUri);// just for demonstration
                }
            }
        } else if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {

            if (receivedType.startsWith("text/")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "TextRecived", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Uri uri2 = receivedIntent.getData();
                String uri = uri2.getEncodedPath() + "  complete: "
                    + uri2.toString();
                txtView.setText(uri);
            } else if (receivedType.startsWith("image/")) {

                txtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Uri receivedUri = (Uri) receivedIntent
                    .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                Toast.makeText(this, receivedUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (receivedUri != null) {
                    picView.setImageURI(receivedUri);// just for demonstration
                }
            }
        } else if (receivedAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
            txtView.setText("-----------------------------");
        }
    }

}
```

**Here are my screenshots:**

[image: opening image from explorer]
[image: when selecting my app empty screen appare]

Comment: Well where does it go wrong? You should give debug info.

Comment: `image is shown in my app.but here no image is appeared.` ???? If it is show then it has appeared i would think. Where are you talking about?

Comment: Please show more complete code. Probably you should start with getIntent or so.

Comment: Use : Uri receivedUri = (Uri) intent.getData();                                         instead of using "receivedIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);"               ^Add Permission also.Hope this works:-).

Comment: @greenapps i want to open image on my app.
i try .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM); but still not working

Comment: SOoyou try that. And what do you get? You should give debug information of course. And if you have exceptions and errors you should post the LogCat.

Comment: no error in debuging 
uri just show 

content://media/extenal/images/media/2964

Comment: Do you mean `receivedUri.toString()` shows that? Perfect. But why are you not mentioning that code? Now what goes wrong after that?

Comment: i am trying to set image on imageview `picView.setImageURI(receivedUri);` i think you are not a developer i posted my all code what wrong here. i am clearly said on Question what i want??

Comment: You have that statement twice in your code. About which one are you talking?

Comment: one for sharing intent and another for revicing. in both one for text another for image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get `Uri` by wrong way. Change all occurances of

```
Uri receivedUri = (Uri) receivedIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

to

```
 Uri receivedUri = receivedIntent.getData();
```

this will get you the right `Uri` of the file. Also do note that `setImageURI` does

> Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) link for more details.

Comment: Yes i already try like this see my code... no way how to get image it not working

Comment: Nope you haven't. The block of code  if (receivedType.startsWith("image/")) you are still using the getParcelableExtra method

Comment: I was able to get your code to work by replacing all the occurrences for method getParcelableExtra() . It was showing the image that was shared.

Comment: Old one also work unfortunatly i forgot read exteral storage permission :)